# Make .gitignore ignore file name contain "_resultlist" in its name

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there a way to have a git ignore file to ignore all files contain the name "_resultlist" in them?

I have files like this:

- 2014_resultlist
- 2015_resultlist
- 2016_resultlist
- lib/main/sub/test.html
- test.html
- test.sh
- test.txt

and so on.

I want git to avoid adding or committing any files that contain "_resultlist" in it. Example like: 2014_resultlist,2015_resultlist and 2016_resultlist

Answer (score 4):

Note: `**/*_resultlist` would ignore files *and* folders alike (ending with `_resultlist`)

And once a folder is ignored, any of its content is ignored as well.

A more robust way to ignore only *files* is to then whitelist folders:

```
**/*_resultlist
!**/
```

In your particular case, this is not needed, but in general, this is how you ignore *files* ending with a particular suffix.

To check what is actually ignored, you can use:

```
git check-ignore -v -- afile
```

You will see (if ignored) the exact `.gitignore` file and `.gitignore` rule which does select that file to be ignored by `git status`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be as simple as putting this on its own line:

```
**/*_resultlist
```

This will ignore any files with the suffix in any directories.